# Android superuser access from my application

Tags: android, shell, toolbox, busybox, root

I'm writing an application that should modify some files it doesn't have access to: another application's database, default.prop, etc.

Currently, it is done with "su" request and temporary "chmod 0777" to required files. But I think that's not the best solution.

Is there any preferable way to do such operations?

And how, for example, I should check if shell commands (chown, chmod, grep, find) are supported by toolbox (if there's not busybox)?

Comment: It doesn't make me feel good that your app is going to change files that it doesn't have permission to change. I don't think I want this app on MY device.

Comment: So, you are not using Root Explorer, for example? My app is device-specific and it changes some annoying settings which you are not able to change with standard UI on Samsung Galaxy series. That settings are obvious and must-have for most users.

Comment: I don't think so and they have no root access.

Comment: If you do not have an answer, then stop posting comments, please. I don't need your opinion on rooting Android phones and using that privileges. Thanks!